# How to replace video clip with background image after it is played in JavaFX?

Tags: events, javafx

New to JavaFx. 
I have managed to open a window that plays automatically a small video clip. 
Once video clip finished, I would like the program to display the regular background.
So far no luck and frankly stuck with no idea.
Thank you
J

Comment: Did you try [`setOnEndOfMedia`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnEndOfMedia-java.lang.Runnable-)?

Comment: Hi James: I did but I guess I do not use it properly. To check if it works I set it up to be "done" when clip is finished. It works, but I do not know how to get the regular background back.